# Powershell Set-Content seems to corrupt my SSIS .dtsx files

Tags: xml, powershell, encoding, ssis

I have build a simple powershell script which replaces the xml path configuration in dtsx files using get-content / set-content.

```
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $searchtext , $replacetext} | Set-Content $file.PSPath
```

When i use it and try to run the package from sql server agent job i get an error saying:

```
"Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML format."
```

If i edit the file myself with sublime and not use the script it is ok.

The replace is happening ok, i used kdiff to compare the files and there are no differences.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set-Content defaults to ASCII encoding. I wonder if the file was UTF8 with a BOM.  Try using `Set-Content $file.PSPath -Enc Utf8`.  Or maybe it was Unicode, in that case use `-Encoding Unicode`.

FWIW these types of problems is why I added Edit-File to the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com).  With it you can edit the file like so:

```
Edit-File $file.PSPath $searchText $replacementText
```

And it handles preserving the file's original encoding.

Comment: That was it! I compared with kdiff the original file with the output and it was System <-> UTF8 ..I added the switch and is now ok. thanks! One question though .Your extention how does it handle it with speed?

Comment: Performance of the Edit-File command is pretty good - should be better than using pipelined PowerShell commands as Edit-File does it all in a single, binary (C# implemented) command.